# Triggering method dependent on action on second window

Tags: c#, wpf, methods, window

Please can someone tell me the technique that would be used, for the following scenario.

I would like to authenticate users, before I allow my code to perform another action.

I have a method that opens a new window that contains my authentication form (username and password).

```
    private bool userLogin()
    {
        Window loginInterface = new Window()
        {
            Title = "Please Login",
            Content = new login(),
            Height = 282,
            Width = 300,
            ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize,
            WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner

        };

        loginInterface.Owner = this;

        loginInterface.ShowDialog();

        return true;

    }
```

I'm calling this method like so, on button click:

```
    private void perform_action(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!userLogin())
        {
            // Failed login, do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            // Authentication successful, perform action
            delete_item();
        }
    }
```

The window opens fine, but how can I now make my method return true or false based on the what the user does on the opened form?

So when the user clicks the login button named `login_button`, my code already validates the credentials, but I need the 'bool' value sent back.

Can I make my first window almost wait for an action to be performed on another window and get the response back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Window.ShowDialog()` method actually already returns a `bool?`.  This can be set at any point from within the `Window` by setting (for example) `this.DialogResult = true`.  You can then close the window and access the value from the calling code.

To close the window with a result:

```
this.DialogResult = true;
```

...and then to use that result in the calling code:

```
var myWindow = /*create window*/;
var result = myWindow.ShowDialog();
if (result == true)
{
     //...
}
```

Comment: 1. `Close` is not necessary 2. `result` is nullable, so that statement won't work like this

Comment: Thank you for this!  I was having trouble at first because I had the Window set as a UserControl.  Once I changed that, I was able to access the DialogResult variable.

Answer (score 0):

To close the login screen you can set [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dialogresult.aspx) to true or false, and [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) returns this value. For other things you can create [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) on the second window and subscribe to them on the first.

Answer (score 0):

`userLogin` should return something other than true.

I would do something like this (based on the code shown):

```
return loginInterface.WasSuccessful;  // you'd have to add this property
```